# twilio Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for debug conflicting with internal version by Android

Tags: android, twilio, okhttp, twilio-api

I'm trying to use Twilio and I added the following dependency to gradle: 
compile 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio:7.11.0'.

When I sync I get:
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for ... as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

I've seen a few questions about this, but none of them are working. I'm using OkHttp library for Http requests.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android) or [this](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android) instead. Most likely, `com.twilio.sdk:twilio` is for other Java programs, not Android.

Comment: It works with Twilio Client Android SDK or with Programmable Voice SDK. I wanted to use Twilio Rest API, but it does not seem to go further because I have some warnings related to what I described above. Probably like you said, com.twilio.sdk:twilio is for other Java programs.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We recommend that you do not use the REST API directly from your Android application, since it would mean that you would need to either embed or make available your Account SID and Auth Token. A malicious user could then intercept or decompile your application to gain access to your account. Thus, the Twilio Java library doesn't build for Android.

Instead, we recommend you make your calls to the Twilio API from a server you own and then set up the communication between your app and your server. Here is an example of how we recommend you [send SMS messages with Android](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html).